# android constraintlayout, is it possible to set mmaxWidth by percentage

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Having three textView, the content size varies. Want to show ellipsis if the content to to big.

```
|[aaa][bbb][ccc]           |
|[aaaaaaa...][bbbbbb.][ccc]| 
|[aaa][bbbbbb.......][c...]|   
|[aaaa...][bbbb...][ccc...]|
```

could not find a solution using constraintLayout for it. This one does not do wanted,
but if it can set the the [a] with a maxWidth by percentage of the parent width, so that it can leave some width for the [b] and [c]

something like (but it does not exist)

```
android:maxWidth="50%"
```

Any suggestion?what is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="22dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greenTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/blueTextView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Firdsfgsdfgasdsdfasdsdfsds" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blueTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"

        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"

        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/greenTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/orangetextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/greenTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Secoasdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orangetextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/blueTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/blueTextView"
        tools:text="Third Very Long Text 123456789" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple workaround for that, to achieving the logic of percentage for width we can use two vertical `Guideline` that can split the screen into three sections:

This is a simple code I wrote for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="22dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greenTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Firdsfgsdfgasdsdfasdsdfsds" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/blueTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/greenTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Secoasdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/orangetextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/blueTextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline3"
        tools:text="Third Very Long Text 123456789" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

you can customize spaces by `margins`, any comments or modifications please tell me,cheers

Comment: it does not work. it gives the fix width when it has less text it still keeps that width instead of flow to left.

Comment: so please explain in details what you mean by width percentage, you have 100% screen width tell me how u need they being distributed, please.